# Noise-cancelling headphones better than Bose QC35

Tags: headphones

I work in an office that can be very chatty at times. In order to concentrate during noise peaks, I need headphones with very good noise cancellation.
I tried the Bose QC35 when they were released, since they allegedly had some of the best noise cancellation. This was before ANC was nerfed by firmware updates.

But they just did not cut it for me. While the active noise cancellation is pretty good overall, it does a poor job at filtering out voices and speaker phone calls.
Adding more noise to drown the ambient noises (i.e. playing music) works, but only if I set the volume so high that it gets distracting by itself.

Are there any ANC headphones that do a better job than the Bose QC35, especially for cancelling out conversations and phone calls?
Using passive noise cancellation would not be socially accepted in the environment I work at, so ANC headphones it is ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand and feel your pain in an almost daily occurrence!

I personally use the Sony WH-1000XM3. I find it to be a lot better than the Bose you mentioned. It's a bit cheaper than the Bose as well.

[Amazon Link for the headset](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07G4MNFS1)

Comment: Read a few reviews, sounds quite good, and found them for 278€ on Amazon. Will report back after I used them for a while.

Comment: Well, the noise-cancelling seems to be a little bit better than what I experienced with Bose. Not perfect, but I guess this is about as good as it gets with current technology. A minor annoyance are the included cables: both are awfully short. And in terms of comfort, I preferred the QC35.